# How to re-write Redundant Assignment?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, sonarqube

I have this code:

```
    If SalaryCbx.Checked = True Then
        fundSalary = "S"  <- Throws an error
    Else
        fundSalary = "N"  <- Throws an error
    End If
```

SonarQube throws a "Critical" error:

*Assignment is not used
(Category: Redundancies in Code)
resharper-vbnet   RedundantAssignment 
Value assigned is not used in any execution path*

Is there a better way to write this kind of logic? 
I tried a `Select Case` statement but it also threw the error.

I also use this same code except for different variables/checkboxes and it works fine - no errors.

Update: Here's where I am using it.

```
    Dim insertQry As String = "INSERT INTO FUND (FUND_ID, FUND_NM, FUND_TICKER_NM, FUND_SALARY_IND, FUND_BONUS_IND, FUND_ALCTN_IND, BEG_DT, END_DT) "
    insertQry &= "          VALUES(@FundID, @fndName, @fndTicker, @fndSalary, @fndBonus, @fndAllocation, @fndBeg, @fndEnd) "

     'Code omitted

        'Declare Connection String
        Using sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(myConn)
            'Declare variable for SQL command
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(insertQry)
                With cmd
                    .Connection = sqlConnection
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FundID", id)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fndName", fundName)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fndTicker", fundTicker)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fndSalary", fundSalary)
```

Comment: The message is saying that you're not reading the assigned value in any other part of your code. If this code isn't needed currently, you could just eliminate it. It's also possible that you made something like a copy-and-paste error and are accidentally reading a different variable where you intend to read this one.

Comment: Check and make sure they're actually the same variable (e.g. that you don't have a local shadowing a member or similar). It could also just be a false positive.

Comment: DOH! Spot on. If you want to post your comments in an answer I'll accept and upvote. I overlooked a copy/paste error. Must be one of those days. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is saying that you're not reading the assigned value in any other part of your code. Possible reasons:

- You made an mistake (like a copy-and-paste error) and are accidentally reading a different variable where you intend to read this one.
- The reading code has shadowed the written variable with an identically-named variable in a narrower scope.
- Old code that no longer needs to be present because nothing is meant to read the variable.
- False positive in the checker.